# retain original value with ko.mapping.fromJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js

I have a value defined as ko.observableArray([]) and use ko.mapping.fromJS to append data from ajax into it. However, when i use ko.mapping.fromJS again, the new data fetch from ajax call replace self.SampleArray instead of append new data. I would like to retain the previous data. How could it be done?

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.SampleArray = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  $.ajax({
    ..
    ..
    success: function() {       
       ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.sampleArray());
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pushing it into `observableArray` rather replacing it

**viewModel:**

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.sampleArray = ko.observableArray([{
        'Hours': 0.5
    }])
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert('Mock of ajax call')
        var newData = ko.mapping.fromJS(data1)();
        self.sampleArray.push.apply(self.sampleArray,newData) 
    }, 2000);
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel())
```

***Advantage of push.apply over traditional loop statements:***

> If your array / collection has multiple items and if you add
>   (array.push(item) one by one then the subscribers will be notified for
>   each and every push / add operation. Then the UI will have that number
>   of refresh. That will hurt the UI page performances.
>
> But if you use **array.push.appy** , then  you can still add multiple
>   items, but subscribers will be notified only once.
>
> That is the difference and the advantage / usage of this
>   array.push.apply function.

sample working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/nejdqktq/8/)**

sample working fiddle with utils.forEach **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/nejdqktq/2/)**

Comment: what is the advantage of using ko.utils.arrayForEach over $.each ?

Comment: @desmondlee `arrayForEach` is from knockout utility lib where as `.each` is a jquery version . `.each` requires jquery library to function as it's a non ko function . both do the same thing .

Comment: @desmondlee optimized code using `push.apply` check the update cheers